# Как проверить что сообщение написано полностью или частично капсом?

Tags: java

Как проверить что сообщение написано полностью или частично(>75%) капсом?

Comment: регуляку не рассматривали?

Comment: Их использование допустимо, но ничего подобного ещё не делал с ними.

Comment: Посчитать количество буквенных символов. Посчитать количество капс-букв. Вычислить процент. Подсчёт проще всего вести, заменяя регуляркой символы (все буквы или только капс-буквы) на пустую строку и вычисляя уменьшение длины строки по сравнению с исходной.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы подсчитать количество заглавных букв можно использовать [`Character.isUpperCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase(char)).

Например, через Stream API для строки `text`:

```
int upperCaseLettersCount = (int) text.chars().filter(Character::isUpperCase).count();
```

На полученном количестве можно строить логику по необходимости.